# How to resume background music after recording

Tags: avaudiosession

In my camera view controller's viewWillAppear method I set the audio session's category to record and also set it active. On its viewWillDisappear's method I set the category to ambient and deactivate it. If I have music playing on the background, when I go to my camera view controller it stops, which is fine. However, when I leave, the music that was playing on the background is not resumed, even I'm telling the OS that my audio session is no longer active.

What else needs to be done in order to resume background music?

Answer (score 10):

Found the way. Put this code whenever you want to resume background music:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO
                               withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation
                                     error:&error];
```

Answer (score 4):

For SWIFT 4:

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
   } catch {
        print ("setActive(false) ERROR : \(error)")
   }
```

although "options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation" is commonly seen with setActive(true), it actually is NOT required on true, but is MANDATORY on false -- if one desires the audio to resume, that is. ;-)